# Error in bash script while reading a file

Tags: bash

The following is a script I wrote to run an  executable `./runnable` on argument/input file `input`.

It takes standard input from another file called `final_file` and outputs it to a file called `outfile`. There are 91 lines in `final_file` (i.e., 91 different standard space delimited inputs) and therefore the bash script should call the `./runnable` input 91 times.

But, I am not sure why it is calling it only one time. Any suggestions on what's going on wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTFILE=outfile
(

a=0

while read line
do 

    ./runnable input
    echo "This is line number: $a"
    a='expr $a+ 1'

done<final_file

) >$OUTFILE
```

To clarify, the `final_file` looks like

```
_ _DATA_ _
2,9,2,9,10,0,38
2,9,2,10,11,0,0
2,9,2,11,12,0,0
2,9,2,12,13,0,0
2,9,2,13,0,1,4
2,9,2,13,3,2,2
```

and so on. One line, at a time, is the standard input. Number of lines in `final_file` correspond to number of times the standard input is given. So in the above case, the script should run six times as there are six lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll hazard that **`./runnable` seeks all the way through stdin**.  With no input left to *`read`*, the `while` loop ends after one iteration.

Reasoning:  your example *Works For Me* `(TM)`, substituting a file I happen to have (`/etc/services`) for `final_file` and commenting out the line that invokes `./runnable`.

On the other hand, if I replace the `./runnable` invocation with a one-liner that simply seeks and discards standard input (e.g., *`cat - > /dev/null`* or *`perl -ne 1`*), I get the behavior you describe.

(Note that you want backticks or `$()` around the call to *`expr`*.)

Answer (score 0):

- Run your shell script with the -x
  option for some debugging output.
- Add `echo $line` after your `while read line; do`
- Note that `while read line; do echo $line; done` does not read space separated input, it reads **line** separated input.

Comment: @Zan: Doing that confirms the fact that the script is reading only the first line of 'finalfile' and not rest. But, I want to know how to resolve this issue or what is going on thats making it do the same.